# Merge columns with same header no duplicate columns

Tags: python, r

So I've tried looking into many articles explaining how merge or concat, join, etc. work for pandas in python, or just general r. Nothing seems to work the way I need when I test it out with my data. I'm going to post sample data with arbitrary numbers and headers that has the characteristics of my data and how I want it to look in the final product. I generally have tried using Genus as my common column because that column has the most common info and all other columns are information describing that column. These are text files.

Dataframe 1:

```
Genus    Data    Facts    Info
Dog    1    2    N/A
Cat    3    1    N/A
Elephant    N/A    3    3
Pig    N/A    N/A    N/A
Mouse    N/A    N/A    N/A
```

Dataframe 2:

```
Genus    Info    Stats
Dog    2    3
Cat    1    2
Elephant    N/A    1
Pig    N/A    N/A
Mouse    N/A    N/A
Bird    N/A    N/A
```

Desired Outcome:

```
Genus    Data    Facts    Info    Stats
Dog    1    2    2    3
Cat    3    1    1    2
Elephant    N/A    3    3    1
Pig    N/A    N/A    N/A    N/A
Mouse    N/A    N/A    N/A    N/A
Bird    N/A    N/A    N/A    N/A
```

Is there any way to create this outcome using either python or r? I'm kind of new to python and r and don't know /all/ of the ins and outs, so I may just be missing something or not searching with the right terminology, but I have been trying for about 3 weeks now reading what other people have done to similar situations and trying to bank off of them. I can't use Excel because it auto changes some number inputs into dates and does other small changes that if someone tried to redo it, they may not realize to fix those nuances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do that with pandas in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4), columns=['a','b','c','d']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2), columns=['e','f'])

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
#          a         b         c         d         e         f
# 0 -1.181554  0.918146  0.547498 -0.409452 -1.852066 -0.377525
# 1  0.508757  0.219863  1.945935  1.285512 -0.076156  0.172197
# 2 -0.186153 -1.784728 -0.200416  1.873692  2.097818  0.575256
```

(McKinney, Python for Data Analysis, p. 186)

edit:

Oops, I noticed you have an Info column in both dataframes. I think this would work better in that case:

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
```

> you can think of it as "patching" missing data in the calling object with data from the object you pass (McKinney)

edit:

Another quote from McKinney, p177 provides

> `pandas.merge` connects rows of DataFrames based on one or more keys [like a database join]
>
> `pandas.concat` glues or stacks together objects along an axis
>
> `combine_first` enables splicing together overlapping data to fill in missing values in one object with values from another

Comment: Oh, so in this case, the "patching" is taking the information from df2 and filling the spaces that are in df1 while still keeping the different column and rows from df2?

Comment: That's brilliant! Is it really that simple? I haven't seen this "df1.combine_first()" anywhere, I've only ever seen .merge, .join, and .concat with conditions such as by=outer or some other complicated things that didn't make sense to my novice self. I appreciate that a lot. Is it part of numpy? Because that may be why I haven't seen it before. This should work for larger tables also, correct?

Comment: Many pandas things are designed after numpy features. So combine_first() method is available on numpy Series, as well as pandas DataFrame. The only reason I imported numpy above was to quickly create some random dataframes.  I will add an edit from McKinney's text which explains the options for combining and merging. Glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
 cols_to_use = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns) # removes all duplicates
 cols_to_use=cols_to_use.union(['Genus']) #since we need Genus for joining df's keep that one

 df3=pd.merge(df1,df2[cols_to_use],on='Genus')
```

output

```
      Genus  Info  Stats  Data  Facts
0       Dog   2.0    3.0   1.0    2.0
1       Cat   1.0    2.0   3.0    1.0
2  Elephant   NaN    1.0   NaN    3.0
3       Pig   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
4     Mouse   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I didn't want a duplicate column in my final product, but thank you.

Comment: Removed duplicate columns

Comment: Interesting, but I'm assuming that would take manual input of every single column header? That would take a long time because my files have upwards of 70 columns in some cases. Thank you very much for your time! This may work for some other smaller ones that I have :)